# Can we tell when a distinction (e.g., infer vs imply) is likely to be lost?

Tags: word-usage

Is there some way to tell that a distinction is doomed to disappear?  When did the difference between presently and currently disappear?  Presently and momentarily? The distinction between imply and infer seems to be hanging on, but will spell-check inevitably kill the difference between principal and principle?  The question is not whether the disappearance of distinctions is good or bad, but when the tipping point -- or tipping range -- occurs.

Comment: To predict when some distinction is 'doomed'? Use science instead of anecdotes. Use corpora to count instances, and use statistics to see if a noticed trend is real or not.

Comment: I've never heard *imply* and *infer* conflated. Let it also be said that the meaning of *presently* hasn't changed to be synonymous with *currently*. It at first meant *currently* but evolved to mean *shortly*; over time, however, people began to think that this was nonsensical, and so they changed the meaning back to what it logically should be: the adverb of *present*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we can't predict how English will evolve.

Comment: `Infer` and `imply` are two totally different concepts. The fact that some users confuse between them isn't a reason to "lose distinction"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Garner's Modern American Usage* has a useful feature called the *Language-Change Index* (page xxxv), whose purpose "*is to measure how widely-accepted various linguistic innovations have become*".

The *Language-Change Index* has 5 stages, as outlined in this *[Language Log](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=4358)* entry by Mark Liberman. Garner's key to the 5 stages includes 10 amusing, if idiosyncatic, analogies. So the *Olfactory Analogy* lists the 5 stages as follows:

> - Stage 1: Foul
> - Stage 2: Malodorous
> - Stage 3: Smelly
> - Stage 4: Vaguely odorous
> - Stage 5: Neutral

And the *Etiquette Analogy* has:

> - Stage 1: Audible farting
> - Stage 2: Audible belching
> - Stage 3: Overloud talking
> - Stage 4: Elbows on the table
> - Stage 5: Refined

Garner includes a lengthy discussion of how he decides on the stage that any given usage has reached in his prefatory chapter *The Ongoing Struggles of Garlic-Hangers*.

As to the confusion of *infer/imply*, Garner says (page 464):

> Writers frequently misuse *infer* when *imply* would be the correct word.
>   ... Don't be swayed by apologetic notes in some dictionaries that
>   sanction the use of *infer* as a substitute for *imply*, Stylists agree
>   that the important distinction between these words deserves to be
>   maintained.

Garner rates the use of *infer* to mean *imply* at stage 3 of the language change index.

He rates *presently* for *now* or *currently* at stage 4. And *principle* for *principal* at stage 2.